# Error converting configuration from xml to Java

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm converting this XML-based configuration:

```
<bean id="artifactBinding"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool" />
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean
                            class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" />
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="processor">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                    <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

In Java-doc.

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("postBinding")
    public HTTPPostBinding postBinding() {
        return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("redirectBinding")
    public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding redirectBinding() {
        return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("paosBinding")
    public HTTPPAOS11Binding paosBinding() {
        return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("soapBinding")
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager() {
        return new org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient httpClient() {
        return new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient(multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
    }

    @Bean
    ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolution() {
        ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolution = new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
        artifactResolution.setProcessor(sAMLProcessorImpl());
        return artifactResolution;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("artifactResolution")
    public org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding() {
        return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine(),
                artifactResolution());
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("processor")
    public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
        Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<SAMLBinding>();
        bindings.add(redirectBinding());
        bindings.add(postBinding());
        bindings.add(soapBinding());
        bindings.add(paosBinding());
        bindings.add(artifactBinding());
        return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("sAMLProcessorImpl")
    public SAMLProcessorImpl sAMLProcessorImpl() {
        return new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding());
    }
```

... But at runtime, Spring returns me this error: [Error stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/0tsabntj)

What is wrong with the "artifactBinding" bean?

Comment: It's not the same config `SAMLProcessorImpl` has much more procesors in the  java config version and this probably involves a cycle or something. By the way, the `@Qualifier` are wrong there, the name of the method is used as the bean name and if you want to change that, you have to use an attribute on the `@Bean` annotation, not the `@Qualifier`.

Comment: A wild guess is that `parserPool` has a cyclic dependency but I don't have all the code so I can't tell. You simply have a cycle in your dependency injection, A needs B et B needs C and C needs A or something like that.

Comment: parserPool's implementation is independent.